# Within .htaccess File https is Off

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I am wanting to redirect all my pages to https. Currently it is doing this but some websites when doing test state that I have to many redirects. This is basically what I have set up within my .htaccess file (for Wordpress)"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**NOTE**: I also have another redirect within this file for another reason, as I have changed my URLs and wanting them all to redirect using a 301:

```
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 /market/(.*)/ /product/$1
```

I'm basically wondering if I have done it all correctly or is there a simpler way so there is not so much redirects. I also notice within my Plesk panel there is an option for this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using thos code in your htaccess file to force HTTPS redirection (make sure to adjust URLs to your actual ones):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.local$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So you are stating I should remove my line of code (which I provided in my question) and replace it all with the code you supplied? And off-course add my domain within www.domain.com?

Comment: Yes, I suggest at least trying to do so.

Comment: I tried this but it made site not work at all. So I changed it back. Any suggestions?

Comment: I hope you didn't remove RewriteEngine On when adding my code?

Comment: Ah, yes I did. I will try again and leave the RewriteEngine On within. I just tested this and now it is stating: www.mydomain.com redirected you too many times.